# moving an object around a Circle

Tags: math, lua, geometry, g-code

I am going to draw a shape like a gear, how can I move a tooth around a circle?
Something like the image below :
[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzEok.jpg)

For example, I need to draw 20 teeth at equal intervals around a circle with a diameter of 50 mm.
I am doing this for a G-code generator program
I draw a tooth first ,Then it is necessary to draw these teeth, which can be adjusted to the desired number by the user, according to the diameter of the gear wheel around a circle
For example, this is a G-code for drawing one tooth :

```
G90
G21
G1 X0 Y0 
G1 X5 Y10
G1 X10 Y10
G1 X15 Y0
```

You can view the output using this site :
https://ncviewer.com/

What is the equation to do this?
I am currently programming using Lua language

Answer (score 0):

n equidistant points on a circle of radius r can be defined (in radians) by

```
theta = 2pi/n
(x_i, y_i) = (r*cos(i*theta), r*sin(i*theta))
```

for 0 <= i < n. In degrees, the equivalent would be

```
theta = 360/n
(x_i, y_i) = (r*cos(i*theta), r*sin(i*theta))
```